# SharePoint 2013 list item property bag and search

Tags: search, crawling, property-bag

**Question for SharePoint 2013**

Does anyone know if it’s possible to index property keys at the SPListItem level?

I know you can at the web, list level etc, but I really need for property values at the item level to return that item in a search.  I’ve tried searching for the property after it was set on the list item and it definitely doesn’t work without some kind of additional steps.

In case someone wonders why we are setting properties at the web level we’d like to have pushed down to all items on the site so we can use them for refinements in search.  We thought properties would be less intrusive to site users.

Thank you!

Comment: Your property column is site column in listitem?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it is possible (more than willing to be proved wrong!). You can't even use a hidden column as they are not indexed. Using a column that isn't added to any views is about the best solution you will get.